# Get coordinates of a list of shapely points

Tags: coordinates, point, shapely

I made a list of shapely `Point` objects

```
in:
alle_Punkte

out:
[[<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>],
 [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>],
 [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>],
 [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>],
 [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>],
 [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>],
 [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>],
 [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a8447c08>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a843fcc8>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x218a848a108>]]
```

How can I derive the coordinates of those points?
I tried to get them using `alle_Punkte.coords` or `alle_Punkte.x` but this won't work because it's a list.

I need the coordinates to proceed my work in QGIS, so it would be even better to create a shapefile out of this list, but its the sampe problem here.

Comment: Maybe in a list comprehension?
`[(p.x, p,y, p.z) for p in alle_Punkte]`? This won't work for a nested list but you can adapt the idea :)
Also note that lots of your points are repeated.

Comment: This results in: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: Yes, I said it would not work because you have a nested list (lists within a list) so you need to adapt to get 2 for loops:
`[(p.x, p,y, p.z) for pts in alle_Punkte for p in pts]`
Exploring coding will bring you further than using an already made solution, I just tried to give you a hint at first.